# Classes in li tag keep seperated when using JSTL

Tags: html, css, jstl

I am trying to add attribute in **li** class if the condition meets like below.

```
<li 
    <c:out value="${pageMaker.startPage == 1? 'class=page-item disabled':'class=page-item'}" />> 
    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
</li>
```

But I am only getting this output `<li class="page-item" disabled="">`  when I check on web browser. I am not friendly to css so I have no idea how to handle this.

Comment: try using escaped quotes: `'class=\"page-item disabled\"'` (not sure if this works as don't really know jstl)

Comment: May I ask if you can use `<c:if>`? I cannot seems to compile the above code of yours.

Comment: @ToanLu I could have. But wanted the code cleaner. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `c:out` here (you don't need to escape HTML characters). You can simplify things by just using:

```
<li class="page-item${pageMaker.startPage == 1 ? ' disabled' : ''}"> 
    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
</li>
```

This also removes some duplicate characters.